# How can I achieve rounded sides effect on UIView? I have attached a sample image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath

I want to achieve this effect on `UIView`. I have tried with `UIBezierPath` but no success so far.

Below is sample image.
[image]

Comment: what you tried sofa

Comment: tried the answer of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33848473/how-to-make-rounded-corners-and-sides-in-uiview-programmatically.

Comment: And what's your current render and what current code? Because the related question seems to do what you want.

Comment: I think related question is more like you need. Just its width = height (square).

Comment: I tested the code. You will get almost likely shape when you set `CGFloat height = width;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make rounded corners and sides in UIview programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33848473/how-to-make-rounded-corners-and-sides-in-uiview-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

Check below answer,

import  `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

and write code

```
view.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
view.layer.masksToBounds = true;
```

Another different approach is

```
[view.layer setCornerRadius:25.0f];
[view.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
```

Comment: This won't works in this case. the above method will only affect the view's corners. The Questioner asked for some different approach. BTW `view.layer.cornerRadius` is calling its default setter method. Both are same.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this can help but, if you select the item of interest from the storyboard, select the following [icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bT4Ck.png) and in the box type `layer.cornerRadius` and change boolean to string and then type whatever multiplier you want.